# how to ensure an installer is free of malware

Tags: windows, malware

A user of the trial version of my Windows desktop application sent an anonymous contact form message stating that Windows Defender warned him my software has a trojan horse. They did not provide the exact error message or any other information like their Windows version. I have Windows 7 64 bit and I got the latest update for Defender and ran a scan on the computer and on my installer and it did not report any problems. Could it be that Defender on a different version of Windows might have detected a problem?  Is there anything else I can do to ensure that my installer is  clean?

Answer (score 2):

> How to ensure an installer is free of malware?

Run it through [Virustotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com), which will test it against 50+ anti-virus packages and tell you if they detect anything.

Comment: No thanks! I read their terms of service which gives them the right to modify my trial software, remove trial limitations and then redistribute it royalty free.

Comment: I see your point, but consider this: how are you going to prevent anyone else (ie: your customers) from sending it to VirusTotal to test it?

Comment: According to their TOS, they get that permission only if the uploader is the legal copyright owner.

Comment: Exactly, and how would they know it was you (the author) that uploaded it?  ;)

Comment: @user204427 You could install every possible AV on every possible OS your software is compatible and then scan it.... I use Virustotal.com for trial software or other files when I download them all the time... I've never heard of anyone getting a redistributed and trial logic stripped from any installers I've ever uploaded (or others) to run through all their AV engines. If you have a major concern and need to scan this with all possible AV on all possible OSes your software runs, then you have a lot of work ahead of you. I'd get the detail next time and not all anonymous contact to post

Comment: OK, virustotal looks legit so I had my installer scanned. one reported virus from each of three AV systems: Invincea: virus.win32.salty.at, Qhihoo: heur/qvm06.1.0000.malware.gen and Rising: malware.heuristic!et.  None of the big name AV vendors reported any problems. So now what do I do? How do I know these are not false positives?